# Dynamically change bean using applicationProperties in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, javabeans

Is it possible to use application properties to set the definition of a bean in Spring boot?

For example:

```
@Bean
public SomeClassImpl getImpl(){
       return SomeClassImplFactory.getDefaultClassImpl();
 }
```

would be the default definition. But would there be a way i could specify in a properties file something like

`getImpl=some.package.NewClassImpl`

Overriding the previous one?

Thanks

Comment: Is the requirement to control the bean instance creation based on an externally configured value ? example , to have two different beans of same type for production and development ? Have you considered @Profile based approach ?

Answer (score 0):

You may consider to use this approach:

```
@Autowired
private Environment environment;

@Bean
public SomeClassImpl getImpl(){
    if(environment.getProperty("getImpl").equals("xxx")) {
        return new NewClassImpl();
    }
    return SomeClassImplFactory.getDefaultClassImpl();
}
```